# jQuery datepicker not closing on IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following jsfiddle works in chrome, but fails in IE11:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
onClose: function () {
    this.focus()
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A8e55/

Goal is to tab to datepicker, use mouse to select, then close datepicker, and refocus on datepicker field, so we can tab to next field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should apply the [Datepicker IE focus fix](http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/06/18/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-focus-fix/).